# Error bash: token: command not found when Issuing a token

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I've been following the step-by-step FabToken tutorial from https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/token/FabToken.html
When I use the command issuing token, I got an error:
bash: token: command not found

token issue --config /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/configorg1.json --mspPath /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp --channel mychannel --type BYFNcoins --quantity 100 --recipient Org1MSP:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp

bash: token: command not found

The expected result should be: 
2019-03-12 00:49:43.864 UTC [token.client] BroadcastReceive -> INFO 001 calling OrdererClient.broadcastReceive
Orderer Status [SUCCESS]
Committed [true]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the executable `token` in your `PATH`. If you know the location, you can directly call it as `/full/path/to/token ...`, or add that path to your `PATH` environment variable.

Also note that the current directory `.` is not (usually) in `PATH` -- you need to specify that path, too, i.e. call using `./token ...`.

Comment: Where can I find the token path?

Comment: It depends where you put them. The setup, including how to setup PATH, are also explained at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html